# Testing Angular Factory with prototypes in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, angular-mock

I'm trying to test a angular factory constructed as the following:

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('PaymentCalculatorFactory', [

function() {

    return {
        function1: function1,
        function2: function2,
        // more functions
    };

    function function1() {
        // implementation 
    }

    function function2(){
         // implementation
    }
}]);
```

I'm using angular mocks and Jasmine with a tried and true pattern that I've used elsewhere but for some reason I'm getting the DI error

```
Unknown provider: PaymentCalculatorFactoryProvider <- PaymentCalculatorFactory
```

Here is the start of my jasmine tests

```
describe("Payment Calculator Factory", function() {

    var factory;

    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(PaymentCalculatorFactory) {
        factory = PaymentCalculatorFactory;
    }));

    // more describes and its and such
```

As far as I can tell all the files are in the correct location for testing.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you define any more factories/controllers/directives/etc on that module? Be sure you are using the getter syntax and not the constructor syntax (with an array as the second argument).

Comment: Also how are you including the files to be tested? Are you using Karma? What does your Karma Config look like?

Comment: @MicahWilliamson I'm definitely using the getter syntax for this factory in particular.  The module 'app' is constructed separately.

Answer (score 0):

It was the ordering in the Grunt config... I had to put the file that contained the "app" module **before** the file that contained the `PaymentCalculatorFactory`.  Thanks to @MicahWilliamson for pointing me towards the config.